# Debugging .NET program crash dump: how to find an item in a large data graph?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, windbg

Let's say you have a crash dump of a .NET program with a large data graph. You have access to the root of the graph via static variable `MyGraph.Root`. You need to examine in the watch window an item many levels down from the root, based on some data property, e.g. `item.Name == "Foobar"`.

How do you do it in Visual Studio? Or in windbg?

If your item has unique type, in windbg you can use `!dumpheap -type` and search for that type. Visual Studio, AFAIK, does not have anything similar to that. But what if all items are of the same type?

One can write a custom data viewer for Visual Studio debugger, that should be able to find the object in the graph, but how do you pass the found object back to normal watch window to examine its properties? I have not found any API that would allow that.

One more complication: in my real life situation the graph was visual tree of WPF windows, where children are not directly accessible as properties of the parent. One needs to use `System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(window, n)` to retrieve nth child of a window.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [NetExt](https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext) which has the [`!wfrom`](https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext#wfrom) command.

You didn't provide many details, but it should look similar to

```
!wfrom -type *.MyGraphNode where ( _name == "Foobar" ) select $addr()
```

Your problem

> where children are not directly accessible as properties of the parent

should not matter here because .NET can access all objects on the heap.

The problem is more the other direction: if you have many graphs and you want to be sure that the object belongs to a specific graph, then NetExt would need additional instructions.

Comment: Thanks! Still does not allow custom code for item selection, but it is getting close. Is there a reference on the syntax of the NetExt where clause? Like, how do I access array items and what-not? I only saw some examples in the github readme, but not a complete list of what's available.

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov: I'm not aware on a more complete documentation than the one on Github. You might want to raise an issue there.